# nmcli - toggle between connections on same interface

Tags: ubuntu, nmcli

I have a device with ubuntu 18.04 and an ethernet port (as well as WiFi capabilities), and I want the ethernet port to be set either to master or slave mode.
By 'master', I mean that I can connect another device to it and it will provide an IP for the other device.
By 'slave', I mean that I can connect the device to another device/network, which will give this device an IP.

I create the two connections like this:

```
nmcli con add con-name master type ethernet ifname enp0s ip4 10.0.0.1/28 gw4 10.0.0.1 ipv4.method shared
nmcli con add con-name slave type ethernet ifname enp0s
```

Each seems to work as expected.

My question: How do I toggle between which of the two is used? I tried altering the `connection.autoconnect-priority` of both connections, but if e.g. `master` is active, it seemed to stay active until I physically unplugged and replugged. Is there a way to refresh the connection? I tried calling `nmcli con down master` and `nmcli con up slave`, but that would only work if a cable was physically connected to the port. I would like to be able to toggle this regardless of whether something is *currently* plugged in.

Thanks in advance (and sorry, I know there's more than one question here).